# Do 2 threads interacting slow each other down?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, computer-science, communication

This is a very conceptual question.

Let's say I have 2 separate threads. Thread A continually gets the time and stores it as a variable, and thread B continually gets the time from thread B's variable and does something with it.

The moment thread B accesses the variable in thread A, does thread A stop running until the operation is finished?

To expand, what if you had 3 threads, Thread A to get the current time and set it as a variable in Thread B, And then thread C to read the variable.

If Thread A is in the middle of assigning the variable the moment thread C comes to read it, does thread stop running until A is finished?

Thanks for the great answers, but now I have 1 more question. If they would interfere, what is the preferred solution to make the multiple threads not compete when communicating. (Conceptually) what would you do to make it so these threads could share the value of the variable while remaining as fast as possible individually?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable in thread A"? Do you mean a thread-local variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory and thrads are two entirely different things. Even a variable that is part of a class which represents a thread is just memory like any other that any thread can access.

However, what complicates this and does in fact cause a slowdown is processor caches: in order for two threads running on different CPUs to access the same piece of memory and "see" each other's changes, the CPU caches have to be synchronized, which can completely negate the (massive) speed advantages of these caches if it happens a lot.

Note that because of caches, thread B may actually see an outdated value of the variable for an arbitrarily long time unless both access the variable within a synchronized block, or the variable is declared with the keyword `volatile`.

Answer (score 3):

No normally not unless you declare the getter and the setter synchronized. If i.e. the setter is being called from one thread and another thread wants to access the getter it has to wait for the other thread to end his task first.

I hope I understood the question right.

Answer (score 1):

It won't make thread B slow thread A down.

But:
1. Thread A may slow thread B down. Depending on the system architecture (cores and caches), every write by thread A will purge the cache line from thread B's CPU. B's next read will be more expensive.
2. If you use a lock to protect the data structure, both threads have to obtain it. Then, obviously, thread A will slow down.
3. If you don't use a lock, and your data type isn't atomic, you may read corrupt data. For example, if the time changes from 0x0000ffff to 0x00010000, you may read 0x0001ffff. Normally, an integer, which is aligned on 4 bytes, is atomic, so if your time is time_t you're probably OK. But the details are platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS and the number of CPU, but basically yes, when one thread is working, the other waits. It doesn't matter much if thread B uses a variable used by thread A, as they share the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they slow down.

And that's because your concurrency checks you coded in the application: since you have a lock, semaphore, monitor, or whatever, to regulate the access to the stored variable, each thread will possibly wait to gain exclusive access to read/write the variable.

and even if you don't have concurrency checks i am pretty sure that memory doesn't allow simultaneous reads or read/write: since this situation might happen, your threads will be forced to slow down a little bit nevertheless